# How to style x-label of two data-sets differently in FrameLabel?

Tags: labeling, style

Hi I have following code, unfortunately it does not lead to the result of the label G1 shown in black and the label G3 shown in red with fontsize 22.

```
Data1 = {{1, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}};
Data2 = {{4, 7}, {6, 10}, {5, 8}};
ListPlot[{Data1, Data2},
PlotStyle -> {Black, Red},
PlotRange -> All, 
Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black],
ImageSize -> Medium,
FrameLabel -> {Style[{{"G1", Black, 22}, {"G3", Red, 22}}],
Style["G2" , 22]}]
```

What can be done to lead to following as label for the x-axis?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `x` FrameLabel to `Style["G1", Black, 22] Style["G3", Red, 22]`

```
ListPlot[{Data1, Data2}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black], ImageSize -> Medium, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["G1", Black, 22] Style["G3", Red, 22], 
   Style["G2", 22]}]
```

[image]

**Update**

As noted by CarlWoll (in the comments), a more robust solution would be to use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html): `Row[{Style["G1", Black, 22], Style["G3", Red, 22]}]`

Comment: Relying on the [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless) property of [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times) to get G1 to appear before G3 is not robust. You should use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.